# Disable/Turn off Touch UI for DAM in AEM/CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

We can change the authoring mode in AEM from `http://<host:port>/system/console/configMgr` in `WCM UI Authoring Mode Service` configuration by changing the `Default UI Authoring Mode` to `CLASSIC`. After this the pages which we open for authoring from siteadmin (`http://<server:host>/siteadmin`) or from user inbox (`http://<server:host>/inbox`) on payload on which workflow is initiated, the page opens in Classic UI mode.

For DAM Asset, when we open the Asset from damadmin (`http://<server:host>/damadmin`), then it is fine. But when we open the Asset from inbox, it opens in Touch UI mode. Also the out of the box workflow emails sent for DAM assets contains the Touch UI mode URL path, something like (`http://<server:host>/assetdetails.html/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits/yolanda_huggins.jpg`)

Is there a seperate configuration to handle this? or the only way is to overlay inbox functionality and send custom email instead of OOTB email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised a day care ticket on this issue. The functionality is as designed by AEM, currently there is no OOTB configuration to change this.

Custom Email can be used to send required details in email, payload URL can be controlled in custom email.